# Why isn't fetch showing data from refcursor in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, cursor, postgresql-9.4

Any idea why this doesn't display data, and how to fix that?

```
create or replace function test_refcursor(a refcursor) 
returns setof refcursor as
$$
begin
    open a for select from accounts;
    return next a;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
begin;
```

Then to try to select data:

```
mydb=> begin;
mydb=> select test_refcursor('a');
 test_refcursor
----------------
 a
(1 row)
mydb=> fetch all from a;
--
(58 rows)
```

Last part doesn't display anything. Does it just not support dynamically type cursors like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last part doesn't display anything as you don't want anything. Try:

```
...
open a for select * from accounts;
...
```

Comment: Oh dear... it's getting late.  Thank you, but I'm going to try to delete the question, as it's all based on a typo.